# shapely : split overlapping polygons python

Tags: python, opencv, polygon, scikit-image, shapely

Is there any way to split a polygon into several simpler shapes?

I have polygons like these :
[link to sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQbzL.png)

that I want to split into several narrow rectangular shapes like this :

[link to what I would need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IMMq.png)

The shapes are always made of overlapping fairly rectangular shapes, that I need to split.

I already tried to use watershed techniques and other ideas based on skeletonising the shape and segmenting the skeleton to be able to split my object into parts, but it splits the polygon into many smaller polygons, it doesn't really fit with my needs. I wondered if anyone had an idea of how to do that ? I use shapely, python and opencv and scikit image for the moment.

Thanks in advance !

[EDIT] :

examples :

```
from skimage import draw 


polygonCoords = np.array([[1876. , 1151.5],
       [1868.5, 1143. ],
       [1864.5, 1123. ],
       [1859.5, 1116. ],
       [1864. , 1116.5],
       [1868. , 1121.5],
       [1870. , 1119.5],
       [1871.5, 1121. ],
       [1871.5, 1141. ],
       [1872.5, 1144. ],
       [1877. , 1147.5],
       [1888.5, 1137. ],
       [1888.5, 1125. ],
       [1891. , 1117.5],
       [1892.5, 1119. ],
       [1891.5, 1130. ],
       [1893. , 1135.5],
       [1899.5, 1126. ],
       [1898.5, 1112. ],
       [1900.5, 1112. ],
       [1901. , 1121.5],
       [1904. , 1121.5],
       [1910. , 1116.5],
       [1909.5, 1120. ],
       [1902.5, 1129. ],
       [1906.5, 1145. ],
       [1904.5, 1146. ],
       [1900.5, 1133. ],
       [1899. , 1132.5],
       [1894. , 1137.5],
       [1892.5, 1137. ],
       [1891.5, 1143. ],
       [1893.5, 1146. ],
       [1890. , 1149.5],
       [1887.5, 1148. ],
       [1888.5, 1145. ],
       [1886. , 1143.5],
       [1882.5, 1148. ],
       [1883. , 1150.5],
       [1879. , 1149.5],
       [1876. , 1151.5]])


polygonExample = Polygon(polygonCoords)

polygonExample = Polygon(polygonCoords)
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = polygonExample.bounds
height = ymax-ymin
width = xmax-xmin
shape = (int(np.ceil(width)), int(np.ceil(height)))


poly_coordinates = np.array(list(polygonExample.exterior.coords))
newPolyCoordinates = (poly_coordinates -[xmin, ymin]).astype(np.uint16)


a_mask = draw.polygon2mask(shape,  newPolyCoordinates)


plt.imshow(a_mask)
plt.show()
```

Ok, now that we have our polygon, let's show what I tried to split it into more basic components :

I tried to use skeletonisation :

```
from plantcv import plantcv as pcv
skel, distance = medial_axis(a_mask, return_distance=True)
plt.imshow(skel)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(distance)
plt.show()
```

and then splitting this skeleton into branches

```
pcv.params.line_thickness = 3
segmented_img, obj = pcv.morphology.segment_skeleton(skel_img=skel.astype(np.uint8))
plt.imshow(segmented_img)
plt.show()
```

I just don't know how to make the transformation back to shapely polygons then. You can also see that the skeleton is splitted in too many pieces.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: so you're implying that you have certain assumptions about the "primitives" that make up this complex contour? AI can solve a lot of things, of course. sounds like a variant of "set cover".

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz yes, totally. It is the output of a sementic segmentation model, trying to segment very particular clouds like those emitted by ship tracks. I am trying to go for instance segmentation, but my only dataset is a sementic segmentation one. I am therefore trying to separate the different instances of my objects that are overlapping on the labels in my dataset. 

It could be a variant of a set cover, but I don't really know how to formalise it